# How would you write this series into a for loop?

Tags: summation

$$\sum_{i=1}^5 (-1)^{i+1}*i^2 $$
I thought it would be something like this but i always get 36 or -36. This is c also.

```
for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    if(i++ % 2 == 0) {
        count = pow(-1,n+1)*pow(n,2);
    } else{
        count = pow(-1,n+1)*pow(n,2);
    }
```

Comment: I didnt see that, i removed it.

Comment: It would be better to ask such questions on stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should suffice

```
int count = 0;
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
{
    count += pow(-1,i+1)*i*i;
}
```

n is just the stop condition, it doesn't need to be referenced explicitly in the loop.

Also you can probably see that you don't need to break the addition into conditions since the arithmetic is the same for both.

Comment: Omg thank you soo much, ive been at it for the entire day and i didnt was just stuck.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have to find sum for 5 terms. So loop should be from n=1 to 5.

Second here is no need of even odd concept.

Answer (score 0):

$2$ things I would like to point out:

1. First of all, the if statement will be
         if(i%2 == 0)
2. Secondly, the body of both the if and else statements should contain $\mathrm{pow(i,2)}$ rather than $\mathrm{pow(n,2)}$.
3. Thirdly, the body of both the if and else statements should also contain $\mathrm{count +=}$ rather than $\mathrm{count=}$

Hope this helps.